# Microsoft Binary Format (MBF) a Float de python a php

Tags: php, python

Tengo este codigo en python que funciona genial, pero no logro pasarlo a php ya que soy bastante nuevo en este interprete, por lo cual les pido ayuda de pasar de python a php.

Transforma 4bytes hexa (MBF) (utilizado también en antiguos archivos btrieve) a un número decimal (float).

```
import struct
b = bytes([0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x85]) # Salida 23
#b = bytes([0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x86]) # Salida 48
as_int = struct.unpack('i', b)
if not as_int:
    print("Error 1")
    exit
man = int(struct.unpack('H', b[2:])[0])
if not man:
    print("Error 2")
    exit
exp = (man & 0xff00) - 0x0200
man = man & 0x7f | (man << 8) & 0x8000
man |= exp >> 1
bytes2 = bytes([b[0], b[1], (man & 255), ((man >> 8) & 255)])
print(struct.unpack('f', bytes2)[0])
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! En esta pagina no transformamos el codigo, pero podemos ayudarte si tenes un problema puntual.

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, he dejado la solución en la respuesta a mi consulta.

Answer (score 0):

al final he logrado pasarlo a php.

Dejo aquí el código por si alguno le sirve.

Saludos a la comunidad.

```
$b="\x00\x00\x38\x85"; // entrada binaria desde archivo btrieve
$man= intval(unpack('S', $b[2].$b[3])[1]; //cambie el formato de unpack para que funcione
$exp = ($man & 0xff00) - 0x200;
$man = $man & 0x7f | ($man << 8 ) & 0x8000;
$man |= $exp >> 1;
$bytes2 = $b[0].$b[1].chr(($man & 255)).chr((($man >> 8) & 255));
print(unpack('f', $bytes2)[1]; // salida con el float correspondiente, en este caso el 23
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).